# Merge or Join two tables to a new table, but PKs differ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Say I have two tables in C#:

dt1 defines Codes; Code is the PK.

| Code | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A-110 | foo | bar | buz |
| A-111 | (NULL) | qem | sob |
| A-112 | (NULL) | (NULL) | idk |

dt2 refers to dt1's codes in a n:1 manner, but has ID as PK:

| ID | F_Code | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A-110 | 12 | 1 |
| 2 | A-110 | 23 | 4 |
| 3 | A-112 | (NULL) | 42 |
| 4 | A-112 | 17 | (NULL) |

So, it's a relation "dt1 1:n dt2".

dt1 and dt2 contain each ~10k-15k rows.

Now, I'd need a result which, if this was in T-SQL, I'd simply get this way:

```
SELECT
  dt1.*,
  dt2.*
FROM
  dt1
  INNER JOIN
  dt2
  ON dt1.Code = dt2.F_Code
```

So, the columns need to be the total columns of dt1 and dt2.

The columnNames of dt1 can vary in name and count (!). Code is fixed as PK, but the other columns may be {A,B,C} or as well {D,G,Y,Z}. This is due to a pivot process in an upstream systems which gives "all the suitable properties of Codes" in this pivoted way. That's why the column names are unknown at compiletime (yet known at runtime: dt1.Columns). That's why I'd need dt1.*, dt2.* in T-SQL...

I could as well get unpivoted data for dt1 (e.g. in a table showing Code, ColumnName, Value), if this helps.

I'd give a try to dt1.Merge(dt2) with its overloads, but as the PK differs, there's no way to match on dt1.Code = dt2.F_Code.

Maybe this sounds like a job for a LINQ join:

```
var result =
  from one in dt1.Rows.Cast<DataRow>
  join two in dt2.Rows.Cast<DataRow>
    on one.Field<string>("Code") equals two.Field<string>("F_Code")
  select new {one, two}; //<-- or what else here?
```

Unfortunately, I'd need this result as a single table (for a given method I have no say in).

And If I try to build a "merged" table dtMerged by combining the columns of dt1 and dt2, and then iterate the LINQ-result, in a way of

```
foreach(var match in result)
{
  foreach(var col in dtMerged,Columns)
   {
     match.one.SetField(col.ColumnName, match.two.Columns[col.ColumnName]);
   }
}
```

which works, I'd wait waaayy too long to be acceptable.

So - any ideas?